# Pivot table - display items with no data

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a problem...

I want to make a pivot table with multiple items in the row section (projects, revenue-type, and 2 more), together with a filter (revenue-type). I then want to display all values (including items with no data) from the project list, in other words the first row section. I do manage do display these values, but at the same time it also displays all "revenue-types", even when I'm filtering on just one. How can I remove all of those, apart from the one I'm filtering with?

I have tried, and I have no clue what to do.

Comment: Welcome R-Beginner, it is a bit confusing trying to understand what it is you are trying to achieve. Kindly edit your question and paste a few screenshots of sample data, one how it is now and perhaps also how you wish it to look. It would help a lot.

Comment: I suggest you provide the data source sample, it's hard to create a sample and provide the suggestion.

Comment: In addition to what people have said about leaving a clear example, and maybe with a dataset to play with, please also put what version of Excel you're working with.